# can we have more than one Bluetooth dongle Active concurently?

Tags: bluetooth, asterisk, raspberry-pi3

trying to set call from ( Xlite => raspberry => bluetooth Dongle => Smartphone => destination )

can we have more than one BT channel with bluetoothctl ?
can we have more than one BT dongle Active concurently ?
I noticed that bluetoothctl use Default BT dongle

thank for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but that will require real understanding of how stack works.

BlueZ should see device.

You should setup in chan_bluetooth correct path to devices.